# How to solve modbus error on solar inverter?

Tags: iot, modbus, pymodbus, solar

I am currently working with one of Growatt inverters, 5 KVA residential inverter, It has two ports one is RS-485 I have connected a Smart Energy Meter with it to control backpower flowing to grid, and on the other port Growatt wifi device was working, I wanted to use my own platform, I used this protocol Growatt PV Inverter Modbus RS-485 RTU Protocol and then connected wire to RS-232 with a Raspberry Pi to read the data and send it back to my server. Now the issue coming is as soon as both devices start to work then inverter starts showing an error. I cannot understand why it was not giving with the Growatt device. Is there any solution?

Comment: RS-485 and RS-232 are different types of electrical signalling for serial communication. They are not compatible. You must use a converter to convert from one form to the other. This question is better fitted for the Electrical Engineering site. You'll have a better chance for an answer there. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, there is an [IoT community StackExchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I want to ask some question about your problem to help you if I can :-).

- Are you going to monitor inverter data on your server? If yes => so, why you don't connect your server to inverter directly (I mean by using USB to the RS-485 converter).
- What is your connection type? If it is Modbus-RTU you need to find Modbus register map to get your desired data. You could find this in the inverter user manual.

Be careful about your Modbus communication configurations and settings (i.e. Baudrate, ID, Parity and Byte Size).